# Is there any countdown widget which shows the timer on the desktop wallpaper?

Tags: software-recommendation, widgets

I want a widget which shows the time left for any event set by the user. The widget should show the time left on the desktop wallpaper. So can anybody suggest such an app/widget?

Comment: What is such a widget?

Comment: I want the widget to show the time left for some event on the wallpaper. It should show up everytime I login.

Comment: i think it's one included in "Screenlets"  for desktop widgets as in the following link 

http://itsfoss.com/install-windows-desktop-widgets-linux/

Comment: Thanx mohtaw... Got It!!